# How to prevent Insecure Direct Object References?

Tags: burp-suite

I've just gone through the video that presents ["A4 Test Insecure DOR Change Secret"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cbSUq_LW3Y) and even though I fully understand what the problem is, I don't know how to mitigate it. Can anyone give me an idea please how to avoid this threat?

Comment: There is a pretty good guide at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Insecure_Direct_Object_Reference_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: replace all sensitive information, that's vulnerable to an attack with a hash. that's smart, I should've figured this. thank you Matthew

Comment: @bonugoso Importantly it's not merely a hash, but a _salted_ hash (or better yet an HMAC).

Comment: I changed the title of the question because "IDOR" may not be the first thing somebody googles for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insecure Direct Object Reference is essentially a combination of two issues, in the most common case: enumerable identifiers used for externally exposed objects, and a lack of sufficient checking for access rights to those objects. The first of these isn't actually required, but makes detection of the issue harder (guessing a GUID, for example, is much harder than incrementing an integer).

Therefore, fixes ideally address both points. The application should verify that the current user has permission to access the object, every time access is attempted. If a user has access to record `3` and no others, any attempt to access record `4` should be rejected. Note that in some cases, just checking on read access is insufficient: if they can write to a record, even without being able to read it, it may allow further compromise. For example, if a `PUT` request made to `/user/1` contains a password value, it is important to check that the same `PUT` request cannot be made to `/user/2`, even if it is known that `GET /user/2` is rejected.

Secondly, object references can be modified to be user-specific. This can prevent exposing information which can be commercially sensitive: if your client id field is `1045`, and you signed up to a site yesterday, you can make a pretty reasonable guess that there are unlikely to be more than 1050 clients. This could be exposed through profile screens at paths such as `/profile/1045/edit`, or through a parameter being passed in a POST request, among other ways. If, however,  the path was `/profile/edit`, and the client id was determined by the server based on the currently active user session, this information is not exposed.

Obviously, in some cases, this isn't an appropriate method: in a CRM system, multiple users need to be able to access the same records, for example, as well as being able to share them. In this case, there needs to be some way to reference them across user accounts. A hash of the object id would be one option, although this needs to be used in conjunction with access controls.

For things like permissions, however, there is no particular need for users to be able to share an identifier. It's more important that they can only set values which are appropriate to their user level. In this case, assigning a user specific identifier to those values which they should be able to access can prevent them even being aware of other values. By performing a server side mapping - `1:read only, 2:read-write` for standard users, but `1:full control, 2:read only, 3:read-write, 4:delete` for administrative users, say - and then processing that when the data is stored, standard users never even see that there are higher levels, and even if they did, would have no way to set them: attempting to copy an admin user's `POST` request setting the access level to 1 would result in it being set to read only, rather than full control.

It is important to note that without insufficient access controls, the amount of information exposed through direct object reference is limited: it might not matter than people can tell how many objects of a given type exist (e.g. Twitter uses (big) integers for tweets), and just preventing unauthorised users from accessing other objects is the important part. Direct object references can be appropriate in some cases, usually where there is a requirement to share a common identifier between users.

Comment: A hash of a sequential object ID would allow the attacker to know how many objects there are by brute-forcing the hash.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of things that I personally ensure to avoid it:

- Avoid exposing your private object references to users whenever possible, such as parameters, primary keys or file names
- Authorization controls like “access tokens ” which are generated from “server-side” should be used
- Make sure access tokens are mapped to users in a way that only they can access their account info
- Validate any private object references extensively with an “accept known good” approach
- Verify authorization to all referenced objects